# Switch/invert left and right audio channels on Linux system-wide

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, bluetooth

### The situation

Sometimes,

- I have my stereo speakers behind me, or
- I wear my headphones with left and right ear inverted for physical comfort reasons.

### My question

**How can I invert the left and right audio channels easily on Linux?**

The ideal solution would be system wide and easy to setup and revert (for when I'm not in the headphones or speaker situation anymore), without interruption of the playing audio stream.

### A limited solution

I use the `pan` audio filter from the `ffmpeg` project when playing a media with `mpv` (`pan="stereo|FL=FR|FR=FL"`) but it only applies to this particular media within mpv...

### Environment

I have PulseAudio and Alsa.

I am using a **bluetooth** audio output that can come and go. Ideally, the solution would dynamically adjust to that, so that the bluetooth output could easily be stereo reversed (by choosing an output within the sound parameters GUI for example).

Comment: Try one of these two [archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Examples#Swap_left/right_channels) methods.

Answer (score 3):

- First, get sink (device) name:

  ```shellsession
  $  pactl get-default-sink
  ...
  Name: device-xxx
  ```
- Reverse channels:

  ```shellsession
  $ pacmd load-module module-remap-sink master=device-xxx sink_name=Inversed-PA sink_properties=device.description=Inversed-PA channels=2 channel_map=front-left,front-right master_channel_map=front-right,front-left
  ```

  where

  - `master=` the device according `pactl` output.
  - `sink_name=` is for `pulseaudio`.
  - `sink_properties=device.description=` is for `pavucontrol`.
- Last, select:

  ```shellsession
  $ pactl set-default-sink Inversed-PA
  ```

And/or : pavucontrol make the change accordingly